# Dataweave standard and interoperability

Tags: dataweave

Sounds Mule's dataweave is *powerful template engine*, but how good is it from the interoperability standpoint? 
For example, any simple to complex mappings in TIBCO Businessworks (only to compare the *transformation logics* and intent is not actually to compare Mule with such zero-code environments) can easily be represented as XSLT files just with copy-paste and better yet, with scripts support in newer versions, which are understandable universally and helps as quick reference to rebuild mapping logic while moving out to a different system. 
Then is it accurate to say that Dataweave (and MEL to some extent) are tightly bound only to Anypoint and just useless for outside world and to be anticipated future pain during moving out? If so, how can it be called developer-level eco-friendly despite such a deep learning-curve?

Answer (score 0):

**Loose Coupled**

Dataweave is not tool; it is *scripting* language. Anypoint Studio only assists in writing scripts like any IDE helps in writing code.

Dataweave can be stored in db and can be loaded at runtime.

**Standalone**

It is possible to run dataweave in *standalone fashion* with some libraries imported in the project (as embedded Mule)

**Closed**

It is not **inter-operable** like XSLT. It is restricted to Java powered software.

**Learning**

If you are developer you can **master** it within a week. *(more than enough)*.

**Upgradation**

Mule team is constantly improving it since 3.7 version. I have used it when it was first launched, if I compare it with today's version, there is a lots of improvement.

It is going better with time. Also, Anypoint's GUI tool ( At my time it was not there). They are making it so that any person from Business can use it *(Ambition)*.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and clarifications. I agree mostly and since I started learning it, it is exciting. The only concern was the interoperability. Had it been in some standard formats support like XSLT or Javascript, its easy to communicate with others on complex mappings. But now it is shareable only with those who are aware of Dataweave scripting, when rewrite (reuse) of this mapping logic is required somewhere else. So it is just Mule's proprietary.

Comment: Yes, It is not **interoperable**. It is restricted to the software running on Java.